# Electronic shop hackerRank challenge in Javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Hi I did not pass the all the tests, only 9/16. so I want to know what is the problem in my code
problem link:https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/electronics-shop/problem

```
function getMoneySpent(keyboards, drives, b) {
    let arr = [];
   let lenOfArr1 = keyboards.length;
    let lenOfArr2 = drives.length;
    let j = drives.length;
    arr = keyboards.slice(0);
    for (let number of drives) {
        arr.push(number);
    }
    return (challenge(arr, lenOfArr1, b));
}


function challenge(arr, lenOfArr1, m) {
    let result = [];
   let j = lenOfArr1;
    for (let i = 0; i < lenOfArr1; i++) {
        if (arr[i] >= m || arr[j] >= m) return -1;
        if (arr[i] + arr[j] < m) {
            result.push(arr[i] + arr[j]);
        }
        i--;
        j++;
        if (j == arr.length) {
            i++;
            j = lenOfArr1;
        }
    }
    if (result.length == 0) return -1;
    return result.sort()[result.length - 1];
}
```

Comment: You should try to search for an input that provides a bad result and provide this sample in the post

Comment: Your code returns -1 for input [10, 5], [20, 2], 7. Wouldn't we expect 7 as the answer?

Answer (score 1):

From the given constraints in the problem statement, you don't need such a complex solution.

Here is the Algorithm:

1. Initialize a variable `maxValue` to have value as `-1`.
2. Start two for loops over `drives` and `keyboards` and take all combinations and sum the value of each `drive` with each `keyboard`.
3. Inside the for loops, check if the sum of `drive + keyboard` and it should be less than or equal to the money Monica has and keep track of the maximum value you get from any combination in `maxValue`.
4. After the code computation, return `maxValue`.

Code:-

```
function getMoneySpent(keyboards, drives, b) {
    let maxValue = -1;
    for (let drive of drives) {
        for(let keyboard of keyboards) {
            let cost = drive + keyboard;
            if(cost > maxValue && cost <= b) {
                maxValue = cost;
            }
        }
    }
    return maxValue;
}
```

Overall Time complexity - `O(n^2)`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It is true that `n` is not very large ( less than 1000) and that a O(n^2) solution should work. However, a rather simple O(n log n) solution exists, by sorting the input arrays. Cannot do more, don't know javascript (I did not downvote)

Answer (score 0):

The following line causes your code to return -1 when there might be a solution:

```
if (arr[i] >= m || arr[j] >= m) return -1;
```

Even though one price may be above budget, you need to consider that there might be cheaper items available. You might even already have solutions in `result`, or they might still be found in a later iteration.

It is not clear to me why you first create a merged array of both input arrays. It does not seem to bring any benefit.

If you sort the input arrays, you can use a two-pointer system where you decide which one to move depending on whether the current sum is within limits or it is too great:

```
function getMoneySpent(keyboards, drives, b) {
    keyboards = [...keyboards].sort((a, b) => b - a) // descending
    drives = [...drives].sort((a, b) => a - b); // ascending
    let k = keyboards.length - 1; // cheapest
    let d = drives.length - 1; // most expensive
    let maxSum = -1;
    while (d >= 0 && k >= 0) {
        let sum = keyboards[k] + drives[d];
        if (sum === b) return b;
        if (sum < b) {
            if (sum > maxSum) maxSum = sum;
            k--; // will increase sum 
        } else {
            d--; // will decrease sum
        }
    }
    return maxSum;
}
```